# Why can't we find the orthogonal complement of a space using the column space and left nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay, so this might be a dumb question and I'm just missing something, but I recently learned about orthogonal complements. From what I learned, the orthogonal complement of the nullspace is all vectors perpendicular to nullspace, so therefore the orthogonal complement is the rowspace, which makes sense to me. There was then an example using a space S spanned by the vectors (1, 2, 3, 0) and (0, 1, 2, 3). From my understanding, to find S perp, we use the transpose of the matrix (correct me if I'm wrong about anything with this):

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

put it in rref, then find the nullspace of the rowspace, which is:

$$
\begin{matrix}
6 \\
-3\\
0 \\
1\\
\end{matrix}
$$
and

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
-2\\
1 \\
0\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I understand how we got this, however, why wouldn't I be able to find S perp using the column space and the left nullspace, even though they are the orthogonal complements of one another? Why do we use the row space and nullspace? I was thinking that it could be since the plane S is in R^4, we would need to use the row space and null space to find x1, x2, x3,and x4. But does that mean that if there are more variables in the column space/left null space basis, we'd use that instead? I'm sorry if I'm overlooking anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand your question, it's due to a preference for row operations instead of column operations. That is, to find the orthogonal complement of a set of columns, we _could_ "column reduce" and then find a basis of the left nullspace. Is that what you're asking?